# Issue copying formatted HTML text to clipboard from Developer Console

Tags: javascript

I'm facing an issue while trying to implement the functionality to copy formatted HTML text to the clipboard using JavaScript. I've created an interface that displays a 'Copy as HTML' icon when I select text, but when I click the icon, not only does it not copy anything, but the icon disappears immediately.

Here's the code I'm using

```
function copyHtmlToClipboard() {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection();
  const range = selectedText.getRangeAt(0);
  const parentElement = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement;
  const formattedHtml = parentElement.outerHTML;

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(formattedHtml)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('HTML copiato con successo nella clipboard');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Errore durante la copia nell\'appunti:', err);
    });
}

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function () {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  const copyButton = document.getElementById('copyButton');

  if (selectedText.length > 0) {
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    copyButton.style.display = 'block';
    copyButton.style.left = `${rect.left}px`;
    copyButton.style.top = `${rect.top - copyButton.offsetHeight}px`;
  } else {
    copyButton.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

let copyButton = document.getElementById('copyButton');
if (!copyButton) {
  copyButton = document.createElement('div');
  copyButton.id = 'copyButton';
  copyButton.textContent = 'Copy as HTML';
  copyButton.style.position = 'fixed';
  copyButton.style.display = 'none';
  copyButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  copyButton.style.background = '#3498db';
  copyButton.style.color = '#fff';
  copyButton.style.padding = '10px';
  copyButton.style.borderRadius = '5px';
  copyButton.style.zIndex = '9999';

  copyButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    copyHtmlToClipboard();
  });

  document.body.appendChild(copyButton);
}
```

I noticed the problem might be related to using `document.execCommand('copy')`, which is deprecated. I've modified the code using the `Clipboard API`, but the issue persists.
I'm testing this code directly from the developer console. Could this be a factor influencing behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Use Code Snippets

Try using code snippets. Anyhow, execCommand is deprecated and no longer works. Try using this code:

```js
let copyButton = document.getElementById("copyButton");
copyButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeText(document.getElementById("copy-text-input").value)
    .then(
      (success) => console.log("text copied"),
      (err) => console.log("error copying text")
    );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="copy-text-input" placeholder="Enter text to be copied" />
    <button id="copyButton">Copy Text</button>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

### Why doesn't the Code Snippet work?

It doesn't work in Stack Overflow, because it doesn't support permissions, but plug it into your IDE and it will work. Also, your JS code is a little cluttered.

### Resources

For more details, see [the Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText).